# Second homology of mapping class group of genus 3

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

In a survey paper of [Korkmaz](http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/math/issues/mat-02-26-1/mat-26-1-8-0203-13.pdf) it is stated that $H_2(\mathrm{Mod}_3)$ is either $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z_2$, but I was not able to find out a precise computation of this group (resolving the ambiguity). Is this group known? Any reference?

Comment: Did you have a look at Chapter 12 of http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780444824325 (Ivanov's survey on mapping class groups)? I don't have a copy right now, so can not check, but usually the book contains everything one would like to know about the homology of mapping class groups.

Comment: @ThiKu : while I think that Ivanov's survey is great, it is pretty dated at this point (eg it predates Madsen-Weiss).

Comment: @ThiKu : I gave a look at Ivanov's survey, but it consider this particular case with rational coefficinets. As in Andy's answer, the integral second homology of $\mathrm{Mod}_3$ has been computed recently by Sakasai. Anyway, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In his paper "Lagrangian mapping class groups from a group homological point of view" (available [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5262)), Sakasai proves that the desired homology group is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: Sorry, typed this on my phone and will not have access to a computer soon.  Can someone fix the arxiv link and the tex?  Thanks!